# Trying to mount drive /dev/sdc: TYPE="nvidia_raid_member"

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 this weekend. Here is my setup:
128GB SSD = Win7
128GB SSD = Ubuntu 14.04
500GB Seagate Barracuda = Files, music, photos, etc

For some reason the SSD with Win7 is already mounting automatically.
I need to mount my "data" drive. From what I read I need to find out the UUID of the drive. But when insert `sudo blkid -c /dev/null` I get:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="6C761AC0761A8B4A" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="25b325e9-3f4a-4406-9a0d-ca51c364f287" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="e685ce58-9a19-431b-bf26-39f5b68a1515" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc: TYPE="nvidia_raid_member"
```

The drive I want to mount is /dev/sdc. A looong time ago I used it with his "twin brother" in raid, he died. So I just reformatted it. Apparently it still is configured for raid.
I did some research and found (on a old post) that if I use `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sdc` the raid mark will be removed.

Since I have data on it I wish to know if this will wipe it or if there is another way around. (Maybe mounting without removing raid)?

Update: I did the `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc` then `p` and it gave me this:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa15239e4

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   ?        2048   976769023   488383488    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

May I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, you should back up your data before doing any of this !!

You can change the type with fdisk

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
```

Display the partition list ;

```
p
```

The partition(s) on the disc will be listed, along with some information. Look for what is listed under the "System" column (it should say it is a raid member).

Change the type by pressing ;

```
t
```

Select the partition number ;

```
1
```

List the available type codes ;

```
L
```

Enter the code that you want, for example for FAT32 ;

```
b
```

Save the settings and exit ;

```
w
```

I don't THINK your data will be wiped, provided you select the correct parition type and don't reformat, but you should seek confirmation before continuing.

Comment: I don't really have anything else to do a backup.. So I guess I'm just going for it.
When I tried `fdisk /dev/sdc` it didn't work, so I tried `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc` and it worked. But it didn't give me any list... just said that `m` was for help.

Comment: I was already root, you do indeed need to specify sudo if you are not root. You need to press 'p' to print the partition table, I missed that bit out ! I have updated my post.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: So it is NFTS (it shows HPFS/NTFS/exFAT) but doesn't have a valid partition table, probably as it is part of a RAID. If you are just going to go for it, without backing anything up, try changing the first partition to the type you want. I REALLY do think you should backup your data first though !

Comment: Ok.. I will backup the important stuff then (I'll be back in a few minutes). I have no way to backup all of it. So I need to change partition 1 to NTFS. Do you know if it will keep getting recognized by Win7?

Comment: Ok, I did a small backup. Just have one more question. The code for NTFS is 7, 86 or 87? Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure its 7, the others are for a volume set. I also want to re-iterate that this may or may not work, but it is what i would do. You know, you can also try one of the partition recovery tools, there are a few available, that might be a safer bet.

Comment: http://findandmount.com/

Comment: I understand that there is no way you can know for sure what will happen. You understood that the HDD is working fine in Win7? Why should I use the recovery tool?

Comment: Because I would feel much better if you backup the important data off the drive first, and I am just suggesting that the partition recovery tool could be a safer bet.

Comment: I'm not understanding why linux doesn't recognize it.. since it is fine on Windows 7

Comment: I did what you suggested (the command) and nothing really happened. So I went further and did the `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sdc` and it erased nvidia meta data from it. Now it doesn't show up on `sudo blkid` any more. But all my data is fine because I still can see it on Windows 7.
About the findandmount program: it couldn't even find any partition.

Comment: Connect it to your windows machine, copy your data off, reformat the drive.

Comment: I don't have any other drive with enough space for me to copy all my files. Most of it is movies though so I'm going to watch them first.. In the mean time I posted this on the forums to see if anybody else has something to add. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I reformated the drive, everything is working fine now. Thanks!